# why isnt findbyidandupdate pushing new comment into array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to add in comments in an array to a main comment. Here i'm getting getting data, using it to create a new comment, and then pushing it into it's parent comment in the children array. But when it findbyidandupdate goes through, the parent comment doesn't have this comment in its children array.
I did a second find below it to see if it returns new updated children array but nothing. I'm inputting the new comment's id into the children array.

my schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var PK = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
var RK = mongoose.Schema.ObjectId;

var CommentSchema = Schema({
    body: {type: String},
    chapterId: {type: RK, ref: 'Chapter'},
    by: {type: RK, ref: 'User'},
    children: [{
        type: RK,
        ref: 'Comment'

     }]
}, {timestamps: true});

function autoPopulateComment() {
    this.populate('by');
}

CommentSchema.
pre('findOne', autoPopulateComment).
pre('find', autoPopulateComment);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema)
```

;

my controller:

```
commentController.reply = function(req,res){
  var commentList;
  var newComment = new Comment(req.body);
  newComment.save();
  console.log(newComment);
  var commid = req.body.comid;

  //console.log(req.body.comid);
  //console.log(req.body.body);
  //console.log(req.body.xxchid);
  //console.log(req.body.by);


  Comment.findByIdAndUpdate(
    commid,
    {$push: {"children": newComment._id}},
    {new: true}


    )

  Comment.find({_id: commid}).then(function(comment){

    console.log(comment);

  })

  Chapter.find({_id: req.xxchid}).then(function(chapter){

    Comment.find({chapterId: req.xxchid}).then(function(data){


      return res.send({commentList: data, comidd: commid, test1:"testy"})
    })


  })

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Changed the update function to this and it worked. Guess it needed a callback shrugs. Anyways thnx stackoverflow! hehexd

```
Comment.findByIdAndUpdate(
    commid,
    {$push: {children: newComment}},
    {new: true}, 
     function(err, post){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      } else{
         console.log(post+"haha")


      }

     }


    )
```

Comment: That's because without callback it only returns the query. There's no execution. [Documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) examples point this for 4.x Moongoose version.